# Horizontal scrolling element only works with shift + cursor wheel (does not work by dragging) - HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive, responsiveness

I have a responsiveness issue on a website that I am repairing. And I have no idea what could be going on.

The website in question is this: https://remolquescuni.com/remolque.../power-box-eco/

It has several responsiveness problems, but to play the one I'm talking about, you have to view the website in a small screen size. (For example, 450 x 760)

You will see that there is a carousel of product images, but the horizontal scroll to navigate between them does not work. It moves the top image (which it shouldn't) and doesn't move the bottom ones.

But, if you keep pressing the shift button + the mouse wheel you can move it perfectly.

[carousel of product images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKwOj.png)

That could be happening? Any ideas?

The web is built on WordPress, with Elementor.
I'm improving the general responsiveness, but with this specific problem I don't know what to do.

Comment: You'll need to try and break your problem down so you can post the relevant code. See [something in my website doesn’t work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: I understand. Thank you.
I used the post you recommended to get the web specific code block (I didn't think this was possible, but from the post you recommended I was able to get to the snappysnippet chromen extension with which it was possible).

Upon extracting the specific code block I realized that it did work, so I guess it's something with the javascript plugins in the template. So I guess I have to check that first. Thank you.